# Query node properties into lists, related node properties into list of lists, tracking hierarchy

Tags: neo4j

Given the following schema / data set:

```
(a:A1)-[ONE]->(b:B1)-[TWO]->(c:C1)
(a:A1)-[ONE]->(b:B1)-[TWO]->(c:C2)
(a:A1)-[ONE]->(b:B2)-[TWO]->(c:C3)
(a:A2)-[ONE]->(b:B3)
(a:A2)-[ONE]->(b:B4)-[TWO]->(c:C4)
(a:A2)
```

I'm trying to assemble a query for some `a` properties, a list of `b` properties (list of strings), and finally a list of `c` property lists (list of list of strings). I'm pretty close using `collect()` but running into an issue keeping track of which `c`'s belong to which `b`'s.

The query I seek would produce a single row per `a` (2 rows for given data set), notice that the data can be sparse, thus an empty array in the results indicating hierarchy:

1. `"A1"`, `["B1", "B2"]`, `[["C1","C2"],["C3"]]`
2. `"A2"`, `["B3", "B4"]`, `[[],["C4"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you aggregate using `COLLECT` [*or any other aggregation*], the other, <strike>uncollected</strike> [*unaggregated*] values in the row serve as the aggregation key, so only rows that share all the other values will match. For your query, you basically need to stack `COLLECT`s in two separate steps like so, to first get lists of `c` keyed by `a` *and* `b`, and then collect all of the `b`s *and* all of the lists of `c`s keyed by `a`, like so:

```
MATCH (a) - [:ONE] -> (b)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b) - [:TWO] -> (c)
WITH a, b, COLLECT(c.property) AS cs
WITH a, COLLECT(b.property) AS bs, COLLECT(cs) AS cs_per_b
RETURN a.property, bs, cs_per_b
```

You can replace `property` with whatever property you want to get from the node, and if it's not a node property, but label or other value, just replace the whole expression inside `COLLECT( )`. You'll also get empty lists inside cs_per_b this way if there are no cs, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question states you want to list node "properties", your sample results list node labels instead.

To display the node labels, the following query should work:

```
MATCH (a)-[:ONE]->(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[:TWO]->(c)
WITH a, b, COLLECT(DISTINCT LABELS(c)[0]) AS lcs
RETURN LABELS(a)[0] AS la, COLLECT(LABELS(b)[0]) AS lb, COLLECT(lcs) AS lc;
```

The query assumes that it is sufficient to use the `ONE` and `TWO` relationship types to distinguish between the `Ax`, `Bx` and `Cx` node labels, and that those nodes only have a single label. It uses an `OPTIONAL MATCH` for the `TWO` relationship since your sample results imply that it is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was the `collect` results of  previous `collect` I needed. Tore's answer explained what I was after & how to achieve; your answer is correct as well :-)